# Varying errors with use of <% provide(:title, “Page Title”) %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I handcrafted several sttic test pages which were working until I added to them the standard call, <% provide(:title, “Page Title”) %> to the application helper for the page title. So I used rails generate controller for each which executed successfully.

I then tried the three pages, again, and got the same error on two and a different error on the third. Following are the error messages. Note the single quotes around "Tige" on the "undefined local variable '"Tige"' line. Why the error, and why different errors for the same line of code?

```
SyntaxError in StaticPagesController#betty
```

/home/ubuntu/workspace/pets_sandbox_app/app/views/static_pages/betty.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' '.freeze; provide(:title, “Betty Boop”) ^
    Extracted source (around line #2):
        1 
        2 <% provide(:title, “Betty Boop”) %>
        3

## Betty  (Boop)

```
  <% provide(:title, “Betty Boop”) %>
  <h1>Betty  <small>(Boop)</small></h1>

SyntaxError in StaticPagesController#buster
```

/home/ubuntu/workspace/pets_sandbox_app/app/views/static_pages/buster.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' ...vide(:title, “Buster Brown”) ... ^
    Extracted source (around line #1):
    1 <% provide(:title, “Buster Brown”) %>
    2

## Buster Brown  ('I live in a shoe')

3

```
            <% provide(:title, “Buster Brown”) %>
<h1>Buster Brown  <small>('I live in a shoe')</small></small></h1>
<nav class="navbar navbar-blue navbar-default">

NameError in StaticPages#tige
```

Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/pets_sandbox_app/app/views/static_pages/tige
    .html.erb where line #1 raised:
    undefined local variable or method `“Tige”' for #<#
    :0x00000003a10380>
    Extracted source (around line #1):
    1 <% provide(:title, “Tige”) %>
    2

## Tige  (lives in a shoe, too)

3

```
            <% provide(:title, “Tige”) %>
    <h1>Tige  <small>(lives in a shoe, too)</small></small></h1>
```

Comment: It's slightly odd that the quote characters in your example are the "begin quote" / "end quote" (e.g. word processor style) instead of standard quote characters. That could cause problems.  The different error might be from the fact that Tige is a single word vs the other two examples being two words.

Answer (score 0):

The more I look at it, the more I believe the problem is the “curly quotes” (e.g. `“` and `”`) in your code. You want to write your code using straight quotes (e.g. `"` ). Using a word processor to edit your code might be the source of your problem.

The reason the error message changed is that the last example didn't have a space so it is interpreted as a single identifier.  The curly quotes are being considered as part of a variable name so “Tige” is being seen as a variable name, but that variable name is not defined anywhere.

Try this instead:

```
<% provide(:title, "Tige") %>
<h1>Tige  <small>(lives in a shoe, too)</small></small></h1>
```

Comment: You were right. The curlies were the culprit. Thanks for the help and advice. Don't know how they got in there, but I have, on occasion copied code bac adn forth between Notes on my MBA and the Cloud9 editor. I shall be more careful in the future. Betty, Buster Brown, and Tige thank you, too. :-]